# Install and use tensorflow_docs in Python using Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I am following the tutorial here: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/overfit_and_underfit

I am getting an error when trying to install and use tensorflow.

The first block of code below works:

import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import regularizers

print(tf.**version**)

However the second block of code below is causing the error below.

!pip install -q git+https://github.com/tensorflow/docs
import tensorflow_docs as tfdocs
import tensorflow_docs.modeling
import tensorflow_docs.plots

ERROR: Error [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified while executing command git clone -q https://github.com/tensorflow/docs 'C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-2i769r71'
ERROR: Cannot find command 'git' - do you have 'git' installed and in your PATH?

There was a similar post which suggested trying a virtual environment however I do not have a virtual environment.  How else can I fix this?

Thank you very much for the help

Comment: Have you installed git? Looks like you're using Windows, so [this](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-install-git-windows) tutorial might help.

Answer (score 0):

From the error `Cannot find command 'git' - do you have 'git' installed and in your PATH?`, it looks like git is not installed.

As commented by @paulicg, Install Git. Follow the steps mentioned [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git) to install Git. Thanks!